# Why is /tmp mounted with permissions 0755 when fstab has 1777?

Tags: mount, fstab, chmod, tmpfs

For `/tmp` in `/etc/fstab`, I have `mode=1777`, but after a reboot, the permissions on `/tmp` are `0755`. Another directory `/var/tmp` is configured in exactly the same way but does not have this problem (see below). This is a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 18.04 Server. The root filesystem is a microSD card mounted read-only.

What is the proper way to make the `1777` permissions permanent?

Here are some additional details (after a fresh boot):

```
$ touch /tmp/test
touch: cannot touch '/tmp/test': Permission denied

$ whoami
ubuntu

$ ls -ld /tmp /var/tmp
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 180 Dec 26 13:54 /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 4 root root  80 Dec 26 13:54 /var/tmp

$ mount |grep /tmp
tmpfs on /var/tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=65536k)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=131072k)

$ grep /tmp /etc/fstab
tmpfs  /var/tmp  tmpfs  defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=64M   0  0
tmpfs  /tmp      tmpfs  defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=128M  0  0

$ sudo systemctl status tmp.mount
● tmp.mount - /tmp
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: active (mounted) since Sun 2018-01-28 15:58:18 UTC; 10 months 27 days ago
    Where: /tmp
     What: tmpfs
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 642 ExecMount=/bin/mount tmpfs /tmp -t tmpfs -o defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=128M (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 2146)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tmp.mount

Jan 28 15:58:18 testsystem systemd[1]: Mounting /tmp...
Jan 28 15:58:18 testsystem systemd[1]: Mounted /tmp.

$ grep -R '/tmp' /etc/tmpfiles.d /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:D! /tmp/.X11-unix 1777 root root 10d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:D! /tmp/.ICE-unix 1777 root root 10d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:D! /tmp/.XIM-unix 1777 root root 10d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:D! /tmp/.font-unix 1777 root root 10d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:D! /tmp/.Test-unix 1777 root root 10d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/x11.conf:r! /tmp/.X[0-9]*-lock
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:D /tmp 1777 root root -
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:#q /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:x /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:X /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:x /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:X /var/tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:R! /tmp/systemd-private-*
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf:R! /var/tmp/systemd-private-*

$ sudo chmod 1777 /tmp

$ ls -ld /tmp /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 180 Dec 26 13:55 /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 4 root root  80 Dec 26 13:55 /var/tmp

$ cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/bash
service ntp start
exit 0

$ uname -a
Linux testsystem 4.15.0-1030-raspi2 #32-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 7 09:15:28 UTC 2018 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Related, unanswered questions:

- [/tmp tmpfs permissions problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195596)
- [How can I mount a tmpfs to /tmp via fstab, writable to anyone?](https://superuser.com/questions/1103101)

Comment: What is the output of `umask`?

Comment: umask is `0007` and it's not set in .bashrc or .profile

Comment: One standard reason for this is that you untarred or unzipped a file in `/tmp` as the root user and this reset the permissions.  You can fix it with `chmod 1777 /tmp`

Comment: Yes, I know I can manually fix the permissions. My question is how to make it survive a reboot (without a bad hack).

Comment: Can you check if you have `/tmp` listed in any of the systemd-tmpfiles configs, under `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` or `/etc/tmpfiles.d`? The mount settings are correct, the permissions are probably being broken by something after the filesystem is mounted... Now you need to find what is breaking them, in order to fix them. Good luck!

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger - thanks for the tip! I added `grep -R '/tmp' /etc/tmpfiles.d /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` to the above checks, but I don't quite understand what I'm looking at.

Comment: Everything looks normal there: `D /tmp 1777 root root -`. Do you have any other scripts or units messing with /tmp on startup? Like @StephenHarris mentioned, a common cause of wrong permissions is unpacking a tarball at the root of /tmp...

Comment: Also, if file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` exists, it will "shadow" the one in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`, so can you confirm that file does *not* exist please?

Comment: There is no `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was part of my initial configuration (because `/` is mounted read-only):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/spool && sudo ln -s /tmp /var/spool
```

Apparently at boot, the system does `chmod 755 /var/spool`, which changed `/tmp` in my case.

The fix was to replace the symlink with a normal directory and add a third `tmpfs` mount:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/spool && sudo mkdir /var/spool && sudo chmod 755 /var/spool
echo 'tmpfs /var/spool tmpfs  defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=0755,size=64M   0  0' |sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Thanks to everyone for the comments which directed me in the correct direction, especially Filipe Brandenburger's "Do you have any other scripts or units messing with /tmp on startup?"

Comment: I'd advise against making `/var/spool` publically writable if you have non-admin users on your system. There are lots of packages that use that directory tree - rsyslog, cron, anacron, dma, libreoffice-core, cups-daemon, at least. I don't know how much they check ownership of various directories. I'm particularly worried about a writable `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: Mark, you are right. Thanks for noticing my oversight. In practice though, the `mode=1777` that I had before my edit did not have any effect because of the `chmod 755 /var/spool` that happens during boot.

Comment: Glad to see you figured this out!